# Unable to install software package due to an unavailable redistribution package

Tags: installation, redistributable, visual-c++-2005

I'm trying to install a software package that needs the Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 redistribution package. But I keep getting an error that the package isn't available on the computer.

It's a Windows 7 embedded machine and I need the 2005 redist for an older SDK.

I have both the x64 and the x86 installed on the pc aswell as the 2008 and 2010 packages.
Also I have tried uninstalling all of the packages an reinstalling them (also rebooting while any changes were made) but the application still will not install. The redistributable packages have all been installed without errors so a faulty install isn't the case.

Also I have tried executing the installer with Administrator rights and so on but nothing seems to work.

I've been searching all over for a long time but I haven't found anything useful so any help will be appreciated

Comment: Release or Debug ? (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4c2bcfca-e0f0-4d27-9ad2-4cd282cc6ed0/vcredistx86-debug-build)

Comment: It's a released package and it's not my own

Comment: "an error that the package isn't available on the computer": what's the exact message ? I am not sure you got my previous question. Release or Debug build ?

Comment: The message says: The Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package is not available on this computer. You May use the link below to download the Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package setup program. You need to install it manually. I have downloaded the files from the link and installed them as described

Comment: When do you get such a message ???

Comment: When I enter the setup of the SDK I want to install

Comment: Ah, looks as if the installer requires the runtime. A pretty funny chicken & egg case... Can you copy the files from another machine ? Or even install VC 2005 ?

Comment: wich files do you mean? The machine i'm experiencing these problems on isn't connected to the tinternet so all files i've used are copied from another machine.

Comment: Dlls mentioned in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\redist.txt